# Plug and Play USB WIFI Dongles?

Tags: wifi, drivers, usb

I just installed Elementary OS and inserted a Cudy WIFI USB dongle.  It doesn't show up as a device.  After poking around the internet, it appears I have to install drivers.  Rather than go through all that, I'm looking for a USB Wifi dongle that will just work out of box (i.e. plug and play).

What are some dongles that are supported by Elementary out of box?  (I'm wanting it to support USB 3).

I've checked Amazon and found dongles claiming to work with Linux, but upon reading the reviews people would talk about having to go through all kinds of gyrations and/or contacting tech support for installation instructions.  Again, I'm looking for dongles that are plug and play.

Comment: Hardware recommendations are generally not done here. However, if you can [edit] your question to include the output of `sudo lsusb` when your Cudy dongle is connected, a proper answer about Linux compatibility can be offered. Sometimes it’s just a configuration change that’s needed to get a WiFi dongle to properly work 

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I've edited my original question from a "what is a good dongle" to "what dongles work out of box".  That way, it isn't a subjective question, rather, it is a "I use this dongle that just worked without requiring any further manipulation".

Answer (score 0):

I feel your pain since I was in the same trouble. The problem is with chipsets and not with the dongle or dongle manufacturer. Unfortunately, not a single webshop is displaying which chipset the dongle is using.

My suggestion is to find a local dealer, buy a few (they are quite cheap), and just return the ones that are not working. Get the dealer to agree with the purchase return, just in case.

Comment: That is a good plan.  I was hoping people would chime in and say "I'm using xyz dongle and it worked out of box".  Failing that, I'll opt for your plan.  I have an old Buffalo Tech dongle that does work out of box.  Unfortunately it isn't fast enough for my uses.  I've been holding off of Linux until the driver situation sorted itself out (heck, Windows solved it back in 1995).  A few years back I installed Linux with the Buffalo Tech dongle and it worked perfectly, so I thought the driver situation was sorted out.  I guess it isn't.  Linux needs to sort this out to be more  appealing.